# Locating my great grandfather's grave in Romania?

Tags: romania, grave-marker

My sister found my great grandmother's grave in Romania. But she could not find my great grandfather's grave. We don't know his name. His children were Israel and Louis Shrager. Where can I get help?

Comment: Hi Jeanie – can you be a bit more specific about when and where in Romania your great grandfather may have died? Even a century would be helpful. You can edit your question to include more specifics using the [edit] button. You're not likely to get very helpful answers unless you provide more detail.

Answer (score 3):

There is no magic answer for you. You'll have to do research and detective work to find your great-grandfather.

It does look like your ancestors on that line are Jewish. Here's some ideas:

1. Locate Israel and Louis Shrager's graves. On Jewish headstones they usually give in Hebrew the person's first name ben (son of) their father's first name. This may allow you to determine your great-grandfather's name.
2. If Israel and/or Louis died in North America, but their parents died in Romania, then both sons immigrated. Track down their immigration records which may give information about their home town in Romania they came from.
3. Hopefully your sister took pictures at the grave and of the graves nearby when in Romania. Often, close family members including siblings, aunts/uncles, in-laws are buried nearby. Did she note any other people at all in the cemetery that sound familiar.
4. Check out the [IAJGS Jewish Cemetery Project](http://www.iajgsjewishcemeteryproject.org/) and the [Jewish Online Worldwide Burial Registry (JOWBR)](http://www.jewishgen.org/databases/cemetery/), which contains 50 cemeteries in Romania with 135,928 burials.  Maybe you'll get lucky.

Good luck, learn lots, and have fun doing it.